# Xcode 10.1 Debugger - How to view the entire collection of objects in Xcode's Debugger?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to easily view my collection of objects while debugging. The problem is when I type po gameBoardSquaresCollection I get a list of memory addresses liked what is displayed below:

[image]

I would like to see the entire array of objects rather than their memory addresses. The gameBoardSquaresCollection is of type Square which contains a property called isTaken. Currently I have to type po gameBoardSquaresCollection[0].isTaken just to see one value of my game board. You can image how tedious this becomes when I have to type this for all 108 squares in my gameBoardSquaresCollection every time I debug.  Is there an easier way to do this from the Debugger Interface or a command that will allow me to do this from the output terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you use `po` with a type, what you are seeing is its **debug description**.

In this case here:

When you do `po gameBoardSquaresCollection` you are seeing the debug description of the `gameBoardSquaresCollection` array. In Swift, array debug descriptions print out the descriptions of all of the array's contained objects.

Since your array contains `SquareView` objects which seem to be subclasses of `UIView`, you are seeing the default debug description of `UIView`s (which knows nothing about the `isTaken` parameter of the `SquareView`).

Fortunately, Swift allows you to return custom debug descriptions for your types by having them conform to the [`CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customdebugstringconvertible).

`SquareView` already conforms to the protocol (since it is a subclass of `UIView`), so if you added the following override to your `SquareView` type (you can omit the extension if you like), you would be able to add the `isTaken` property (or any other information for that matter) to the debug output of `po`:

```
extension SquareView {
    override var debugDescription: String {
        return super.debugDescription + "; isTaken = \(isTaken)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've never known anything about the CustomDebugStringConvertible protocol. Utilizing that will really make my life so much easier. Thanks again.